The [understanding] tag is ambiguous for me
There’s a tag understanding on this site, I saw this tag when I read this question. This tag has no tag wiki (or tag wiki excerpt).
I think this tag is very ambiguous, there are many things that English learners do not understand. Does that mean all questions need to be tagged as understanding? I don’t think so.
Should we burn the tag? Or should we write a clear tag wiki for this tag?
I preferred burning the tag.

This tag has been on my radar for a while as a bad tag—or rather one that's usually quite redundant with meaning and its ilk. If you want to help, look at the ones that don't have those tags (and shouldn't), and do a couple of edits (preferably on questions that need other fixes, given that you can't edit outright). For those that can edit outright (rep >= 2k), remember to not flood the front page with edits.
When all questions with [understanding] could instead be tagged with [meaning], I can merge them cleanly.
